# DialogFragments and Dialogs Android

Tags: android

Everywhere I can read: Use `FragmentDialog` everywhere because it can be independent on `Activity` lifecylce. But, generally, dialogs very often should be displayed asynchronically. However, it is discouraged to commit to `FragmentManager` from asynchrounous callback. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use DialogFragment by all means because as you mentioned it helps in keeping your activity loosely coupled with the dialogue. Yeah there are cases where you might need to show the dialogue asynchronously. In such case, what you need to do is wrap your dialogue invocation code with method calls on the host component which tells you whether it is safe to show the dialogue at this instance or not.

If you are calling show within an activity, wrap the call to show with -

`if(!isDestroyed() && !isFinishing())`

and If you are calling show within a fragment , wrap the call to show with -

`if (isResumed() && !isRemoving())`

This more or less would solve the issue of landing in an inconsistent UI state

Comment: It is not correct. Let's assume that the activity is stopped ( becasue another activity is foreground). Now, `isDestroyed()` returns `false` `isFinshing()` returns false. So, we'll take a branch and commit to the FragmentManager. Exception! Trying to commit to FragmentManager after onSave().